# Are there any library like Ext JS but for C#, especially WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, extjs

I'm looking for a library that allows me to build applications in a way similar to Ext JS, with MVC approach (MVVM with PRISM is ok too on .net applications. I'm thinking about EF to handle database objects), expecially with some nice components like Ext JS provides.

I'm expecially thinking about the grid component which is really useful for managing applications.

I only found Telerik, but it costs $1200 and I'm looking for something possibly free or not more expensive than $500, I know my budget is low but I must consider I should even buy Visual Studio ($900) and it's a lot of money as a single person to start a project.

**Edit 1:**
I found this library but the cost is basically the same as telerik: https://www.componentone.com/Store/?product=145

**Edit 2:**
This is a bit cheaper: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/#main|buy

**Edit 3:**
This is even cheaper but it looks like missing filtering functionality for data-grid, which I think is a must-have: http://www.devcomponents.com/store/Scripts/prodView.asp?idproduct=26

Comment: If it's a small project, consider using Visual Studio Express, which is free

Comment: It's not SO small, expecially you can't sell an application with visual studio express. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can. There's no such limitation on VS Express, you can use it to develop commercial applications. However it has far less features than the full edition (e.g. no addins/extensions)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: This is really important for me, if I have small projects is important that I can create it without spending $900, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **probably** searching for [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) and/or [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/84227). 
Those are libraries with a set of controls for WPF available for *free*.

Plus, to be able to develop something in C#/WPF, you can use [Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) which is *free* as well.

Comment: That's **almost** all I need. However, I'm still missing a good **datagrid** component, something that allows me also filtering like this: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html . It's important because allows me to avoid implementing all search functionalities. Can I use Telerik with Visual Studio Express or do I require Professional?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: sorry, have no idea on Telerik stuff, never used it.

Comment: No problem. Anyway I noticed there are some free grids with filtering functionality, your suggestion is great. I'll mark this as answer is nothing else is coming out.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL You can always roll out your own filtering on `ICollectionView`, it's not *that* hard. :) I even had the very simple 'base' for filtering functionality lying somewhere around...

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor: It's not a programming problem, what gives me problem is the UI presentation: usually it's a "small" button on the right of each column with some useful menus. I should design that UI type and I don't even know if I can place a button on the right of each Grid.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: sure you can, but it for sure could be not so *easy* as it would be on already ready control. But in `WPF` you have styles, so, in practice, can do whatever you want. That is a *real* power of `WPF`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really complete

Answer (score 1):

Not for your library needs but:

For your Visual Studio (and other MS software) requirements, check [WebsiteSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/) and [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx). In short, WebsiteSpark is for startups who develop websites for other companies, and BizSpark is for start-ups who are developing their own software.

Comment: Those are interesting, however I'm using Visual Studio to develop desktop software, I don't know if it's the same.

Comment: In that case, BizSpark is way to go.